# If statement with string length check

Tags: twig, shopware

I'm trying to check if a string is empty in a twig template but I don't understand this behaviour. I want to show a textarea element when the condition is met. Here's the code:

```
{% if item.payload.customizationText|length == 0  %}    
<textarea class="customization-text">{{ item.payload.customizationText|trim }}</textarea>
{% endif %}
```

It always shows the textarea, whether the string has something in it or not. Am I missing something?
It's in shopware 6 by the way and the dump() fuction throws an error because it's undefined.

Also, this expression just outputs the string. Is the length expression not available?

```
 {{ item.payload.customizationText|length }}
```

Comment: Can't [reproduce](https://twigfiddle.com/nmk2kq)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a mistake in the question. It does not make sense to print the variable, only if it is empty.

If you want to show the text area in case the customizationText *has* some contents, you should use this:

```
{% if item.payload.customizationText|trim|length  %}    
<textarea class="customization-text">{{ item.payload.customizationText|trim }}</textarea>
{% endif %}
```

https://twigfiddle.com/nmk2kq/4

Comment: Just an FYI, the filter `length` isn't required - [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/bnlwxw)

Answer (score -1):

You can try it.

```
 {% if item.payload.customizationText is defined and item.payload.customizationText is empty %} 
    <textarea class="customization-text">{{ item.payload.customizationText|trim }}</textarea>
{% endif %}
```